# Spring Cloud Config Server not enforcing BASIC Authentication when running main()

Tags: spring, maven, spring-security, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I have configured a Spring Cloud Config server to force BASIC authentication and here is my application.yml file:

```
# Config Repo:
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: file:///${HOME}/microservices_config_repo

# Show sensitive information for endpoints:
endpoints:
  sensitive: true

# Security for endpoints:
management:
  security:
    enabled: true

security:
  user:
    name: user1
    password: changeme
```

My issue I am having is that when I start the server up as:
mvn spring-boot:run

The server endpoints FORCE BASIC Authentication.
But when I start the Application.main() method, BASIC Authentication is enabled, but NOT enforced.

Meaning I can access configuration on:
http://localhost:8888/client-config
and
http://user1:changeme@localhost:8888/client-config

Can anyone help me understand why this is occuring and how to enforce BASIC Authentication while running the Application.main(), and not just through the Maven spring-boot plugin?

Note, when I use maven to package the app into a jar, then run the generated jar, BASIC Authentication is enforced, but still not through the IDE running just the Application.main directly.

Comment: "BASIC Authentication is enabled, but NOT enforced" - how do you know it's enabled? Also, it sounds like you're doing something in your build file that is missing when you run the app from the IDE.

Comment: I can curl http://localhost:8888/client-config as well as http://user1:changeme@localhost:8888/client-config

Comment: Post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including your build file.

Comment: yeah, something is missing between ide and jar.

Comment: Have you resolve this issue friend?I am trying some similar solution.In addition i need to know if there is another methods to authentication   clients who wants to access its configs. Now,  this is correct to test: http://user1:changeme@localhost:8888/client-config in postman for example. Can you share github repo of your code? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello @MickKnutson Have you resolve the issue? Thanks. I have similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the format the oy Yaml for example to me seems works like this:

```
server:
  port:9999
spring:
  application:
    name: config-server-sample
  cloud:
    config:
      name: ${spring.application.name}
      fail-fast: true
      server:
        git:
          uri: url
          username: xx
          password: zz
          default-label: master
          basedir: '${user.home}/${spring.application.name}/default'
          timeout: 10
          clone-on-start: true
          force-pull: true
  security:
    basic:
        enabled: true
    path: /**
    ignored: /health**,/info**,/metrics**,/trace**
    user:
       name: admin
       password: tupassword
```

Comment: Can you share client side configs as well?